# Get WooCommerce best selling products for the current month

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to get WooCommerce best selling products for the current month.

The following code works fine to get best selling products all time:

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $number,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'no_found_rows'  => 1,
    'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'desc',
    'meta_query'     => array(),
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ),
); // WPCS: slow query ok.
```

Now I'm trying to get the best selling products for the current month, but it does not work correctly:

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $number,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'no_found_rows'  => 1,
    'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'desc',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date( 'Y' ),
            'month' => date( 'm' ),
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query'     => array(),
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ),
); // WPCS: slow query ok.
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873484/4380224 and this https://wordpress.org/plugins/sp-woocommerce-best-selling-products-by-category/

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugins are off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their communities.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to use a date on best selling products, as product `total_sales` can't be related to any date.

To make that possible it should require to query products checking in each paid orders from current month using `WPDB` class and a SQL query like in this custom function *(with an optional argument to limit the number of products)*:

```
function get_best_selling_products( $limit = '-1' ){
    global $wpdb;

    $limit_clause = intval($limit) <= 0 ? '' : 'LIMIT '. intval($limit);
    $curent_month = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00');

    return (array) $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT p.ID as id, COUNT(oim2.meta_value) as count
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim
            ON p.ID = oim.meta_value
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim2
            ON oim.order_item_id = oim2.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items oi
            ON oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as o
            ON o.ID = oi.order_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND o.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed')
        AND o.post_date >= '$curent_month'
        AND oim.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND oim2.meta_key = '_qty'
        GROUP BY p.ID
        ORDER BY COUNT(oim2.meta_value) + 0 DESC
        $limit_clause
    ");
}
```

It will output an array of objects sorted by product count DESC, each object containing the product ID and the count.

USAGE Example *(limited to 5 bestselling products in the current month)*:

```
$best_selling_products = get_best_selling_products( 5 );

// Loop through best selling products stdClass Objects
foreach( $best_selling_products as $values ) {
    $product_id    = $values->id; // Get the product ID
    $product_count = $values->count; // Get the count for the current month
}
```